# Data binding to EF5 DbSet ICollection

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, devexpress

we are looking to move away from using the Entity Framework ObjectSet to the much lighter dbSet.

The problem we are having is not being able to bind to a 1 to many collection of an entity, for example with a typical Order object you would have the Order entity with its various properties and a 1 to many link to the order items.

With EF4/5 ObjectSets, the collection of order items is represented as an EntityCollection, if I bind a DevExpress XtraGrid (via a BindingSource) to this property of the Order entity I get full design and run time binding to the grid.

With EF5 dbSet objects, the collection is represented as an ICollection of objects, when trying to bind to this we only get a Count and IsReadOnly property, no colums (no data-binding).

What would be the best method for making this work ?
Do we need to some-how edit the code-generation template​ for the EF5 DbContext/DbSet classes ?
Can​ we bind to a ICollection ?

As this is now the default behaviour for EF code generation, this must be a known issue ?

Sorry, forgot to mention we are NOT using code first. VS2012, EF5, C#, WinForms, DevExpress 12.9

This has got us stumped, we have been data-binding with EF objects and XtraGrid controls for a number of years with ease, this just doesn't make any sense.

Any help gratefully received.

Mark Harby
Nottingham. UK​

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the **ToBindingList()** extension method as shown in this KB article:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18898